# Return false won't stop loop with value of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, return, each

I have a function that loops through a dynamic table, looking for highlighted cells.

In the following code both alerts trigger.  The loop should stop at "return false", when "previous" is 1.

How can I stop the loop?

```
for (i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#tablegrid").find("td:nth-child("+i+")").each(function() {
       if ($(this).hasClass("highlighted")) {
         var previous = i-1;

         if (previous===1) {
           alert("loop should now stop");
           return false;
         }

         alert("loop has continued");
       }
     });
}
```

Comment: Which loop do you want to break out of? You're breaking out of the loop created by using `each`; if you want to break out of the outer `for` loop, you'll need to set a flag.

Comment: Thanks.  Good point.  Was able to fix it based on this recommendation.  I just set a flag in the each loop and if that flag is present, I shut down the for loop. Thank you.

Comment: @user749798 if that fixed your code problem you should share your solution for future reference if people happen to come upon this trying to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break;` inside `for` loop and user `return false;` inside `each` loop to stop in the middle.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   if (i===5) {
      alert("loop should now stop");
      nextFunction();
      break;
   }         
   alert("loop has continued");
}

function nextFunction(){
    alert("Next Function");
    $('.box').each(function(){
        if($(this).index() == 4){
         alert("loop should now stop");
         anotherFunction();
         return false; 
         
        }
          alert("each has continued");
    })
    
}

function anotherFunction(){
 alert("another function");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```